# SQL server - privileges to get metadata of database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

What minimum privileges my user needs to get metadata (name of tables, columns, procedures, etc.) from database?

I need to select from:

- [database].sys.objects
- [database].sys.schemas
- [database].sys.extended_properties
- [database].sys.sql_modules
- [database].information_schema.columns

**db_datareader** is ok, but I need minimum privileges.

Comment: This is [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187113(v=sql.100).aspx) in detail

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to let user only query metadata of objects, just give him the VIEW ANY DEFINITION permission, as described here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175808(v=sql.105).aspx